# which is a Faster function

Tags: php

How does one go about calculating which of 2 functions is faster. Is there a way to do this conclusively in php? Is there a best practice, like do it n times then get the average, and what would that n be?

p.s. I'm looking for something that doesn't require a special setup if possible. So I'm not looking for a specialized framework, more like a primitive way of getting an idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You can time your scripts with [microtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php). Example included in that page.
- The larger you n, the better your results.
- Keep things like caching in mind. If the functions request the same stuff from the database, the first request may be slower then the rest.
- Repeat a couple of times (so do *m* tests of *n* times)

Answer (score 1):

The few times i have went with wanting to calculate which of the two functions are faster, i have always faced the issue of isolation. The two methods i wanted to check performance on being related to the database, where the bottleneck is the connection to the database.

Generally, it is a good idea when you want to do some performancetesting to keep your tests totally isolated and dependant on no other code. The http://php.net/usleep function is probaly what you are looking for, and you should do the test at least 50 times (250 is way better) to keep the data consistent. The lower the number, the less accurate your result will be.